# Value of $c$ in $c=\frac{16x}{y}+\frac{49y}{x}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

$c=\frac{16x}{y}+\frac{49y}{x}$

Using $AM \geq GM$, I found that $c \geq 56$ but in the solution it has been given that $c$ can also have a value less than or equal to $-56$ but I am not able to understand how? Please help me understand this !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: Try $x=1, y=-1$. Is there something missing from the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, you have :

$$
\begin{align}&16u+\frac {49}{u}-c=0\\
\implies &16u^2-cu+49=0\\
\implies &\Delta_u=c^2-(2\cdot4\cdot 7)^2≥0\\
\implies &|c|≥56\\
\implies &c\in(-\infty,-56]\cup[56,\infty)\end{align}$$

where $\thinspace u=\dfrac xy\thinspace .$

Note that, AM-GM inequality works iff, when $xy>0\thinspace .$

Answer (score 1):

A different way to analyze is to let $z=x/y$ with $z \in \mathbb{R}$.
$$
\begin{split}
c(z) &= 16z+49/z \\
c'(z) &= 16 - 49/z^2 \\
c''(z) &= \frac{49}{2z^3}
\end{split}
$$
So, the relative extrema are at $c'(z)=0 \iff z = \pm 7/4$.

Can you finish?